# x509certificate2 to PEM in NET FR. 4.7.2

Tags: c#, x509certificate, pem

I cant seem to find any info on how to create a PEM from x509certificate2 in .NET FRAMEWORK 4.7.2. There is no PemEncoding class in the legacy framework.

I have a legacy project, where migrating to .net CORE or .NET5 is not an option right now. Could somebody point me in right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct it manually:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<Base64-encoded content with 64 chars on every line>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Flat base64 string is created easily:

```
String b64 = Convert.ToBas64String(cert.RawData);
```

then insert a new line character after every 64 chars in string and insert resulting string between PEM header and footer.

Comment: I did not realize that PEM is just raw data to base64. Thanks.